# Pakyow 0.9 undefined method

Tags: ruby, pakyow

I just upgraded to Pakyow 0.9. When I try to run `pakyow server` on an existing Pakyow project, I get the following error.

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/
  pakyow-2ccd6109e47c/pakyow-core/lib/core/route_eval.rb:334:
  in `action': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from .../appname/app/lib/routes.rb:81:
  in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
...
```

Here's some further info.

```
ruby -v
=> ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin14.0]

gem which pakyow
=> ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/pakyow-0.9.1/lib/pakyow.rb
```

It seems to be set up correctly.

Comment: Fix your routes.rb file.

Comment: Can you share the code around line 81 of routes.rb?

Comment: Here it is (lines 81--83):
    `action :delete do
      Note[params[:note_id]].destroy
    end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.9 the `delete` action was renamed to `remove` (as detailed in the [release notes](http://pakyow.com/blog/2014/11/09/zero_nine)). Try changing lines 81-83 of routes.rb to:

```
action :remove do
  Note[params[:note_id]].destroy
end
```

You can even write it without `action` as:

```
remove do
  Note[params[:note_id]].destroy
end
```

Comment: It worked! I should have noted that I upgraded to Pakyow 0.9. I'll edit my question to reflect that.